# Form Validation Empty

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm sure this is a stupid question but for some reason its not showing the errors. Its only displaying a white screen.

http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/

Should be doing this on an empty form submission:
http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/peach/Template/login.html

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Usermanagement extends CI_Controller { 

public function index()
{
    //Config Defaults Start
    $msgBoxMsgs = array();//msgType = dl, info, warn, note, msg
    $cssPageAddons = '';//If you have extra CSS for this view append it here
    $jsPageAddons = '';//If you have extra JS for this view append it here
    $metaAddons = '';//Sometimes there is a need for additional Meta Data such in the case of Facebook addon's
    $siteTitle = '';//alter only if you need something other than the default for this view.
    //Config Defaults Start


    //examples of how to use the message box system (css not included).
    //$msgBoxMsgs[] = array('msgType' => 'dl', 'theMsg' => 'This is a Blank Message Box...');

    /**********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, Start*/

    // ensure user is signed in
    if ( $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == FALSE ) {
        $bodyContent = "login";//which view file    // no session established, kick back to login page
    }

    $bodyType = "full";//type of template

    /***********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, End*/

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, Start.
    //If msgBoxMsgs array has anything in it, if so displays it in view, else does nothing.      
    if(count($msgBoxMsgs) !== 0)
    {
        $msgBoxes = $this->msgboxes->buildMsgBoxesOutput(array('display' => 'show', 'msgs' =>$msgBoxMsgs));
    }
    else
    {
        $msgBoxes = array('display' => 'none');
    }

    if($siteTitle == '')
    {
        $siteTitle = $this->metatags->SiteTitle(); //reads 
    }

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, End.

    $this->data['msgBoxes'] = $msgBoxes;
    $this->data['cssPageAddons'] = $cssPageAddons;//if there is any additional CSS to add from above Variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['jsPageAddons'] = $jsPageAddons;//if there is any addictional JS to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['metaAddons'] = $metaAddons;//if there is any addictional meta data to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['pageMetaTags'] = $this->metatags->MetaTags();//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['siteTitle'] = $siteTitle;//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['bodyType'] = $bodyType;
    $this->data['bodyContent'] = $bodyContent;
    $this->load->view('usermanagement/index', $this->data);
}

function login()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {

    }
}

function logout()
{
   $this->session->sess_destroy();
   $this->index();
}       

}

/* End of file usermanagement.php */ 
/* Location: ./application/controllers/usermanagement.php */
```

With my template system anyone see what I would have to do to correct his problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked to you on AIM briefly earlier.. 
The error your getting on the page.

"Message:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/xtremer/public_html/kowmanager/application/controllers/usermanagement.php:3)"

Shows either sessions with CI aren't currently running. Or your outputting something to the browser prior to your call for the session.. Knowing your CI install personally. I would say your issue is in part the lack of the missing _construct. Cause your CI install auto loads session capability. Which is required when you want to use something like,

```
$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')
```

Put the construct function back in like with the other controllers you have, and try loading the page again, see if that doesnt fix it.

Answer (score 2):

have you call autoload of the session ? it look like your code have no `__construct()` it is look like to you using another library or helper, just make sure you have  to load them

Answer (score 1):

try turning on error reporting. on the top of your script add this line of code

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL ^E_NOTICE); ?>
```

if that still doesn't work try echoing something at different parts of the script to see where it fails. You either have a parse error or a fatal error somewhere in your script.

are you using output buffering anywhere?

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/xtremer/public_html/kowmanager/application/controllers/usermanagement.php:3)

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 671

Comment: that means that you are calling the header() function with in that file. you just need to make sure that whatever headers you send, MUST be sent before any output. One technique is to use ob_start() at the beginning and ob_end_flush() at the end.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to use that.

Comment: Or it could mean that so much as a space is being put out to the browser before a header or session is being defined.. Also considering its CI, he may also have his session lib not loading properly, while trying to make a call for a session..